# Proposing Marriage to (have) a Synonym

Tags: discussion

[marrage](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marrage) should be a synonym of [marriage](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marriage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Meta Stack Exchange post [How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or “zombie”) tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19754/260340) Sally is correct.

I'm a *little* wary of creating tag synonyms for every single typo that ever happens, even if it's understandable how it might. In this example, it's definitely more work for me to create the tag synonym (and, if Sally hadn't already edited the question, to either edit the question or merge [marrage](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marrage) into [marriage](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marriage)) than it would be for the typo to simply be fixed and then the tag automatically removed.

Also note that these [single-use tags get removed after 6 months](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48418/260340).

In this case, I'm going to let it go, but if we suddenly get a deluge of [marrage](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marrage) questions - or other similar cases of widely/frequently-misspelled tags -  I'm happy to reconsider and do the merge and synonymisation.

Answer (score 2):

It's a misspelling that occurred exactly once, not a trend in incorrect tagging. Just retag that question: you have the editing privilege. The orphaned [marrage](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marrage) tag will be automatically deleted at 3:00 UTC, which is less than 12 hours away.

By the way, the same typo appears in the title of that question.

Comment: It's a misspelling that occurred once *so far in the early development of this site* which, relatively speaking, doesn't have a lot on it yet, and it's easy to see how the same mistake might happen again in the future.  If the site handles that (and other common misspellings) seamlessly, it's a little better off.

Comment: @WBT it kind of just clutters the system. If it's just a one-off question, there really isn't much reason to make a synonym, as it would barely be effective. Ideally, synonyms should really be for different words (like shoes and slippers), not really for typos. Typo tags are easily removed with a simple edit too.